# How to move the polygons of an object into other location by bmesh frame by frame?

Tags: python, scripting, bmesh

How to move the polygons of an object into other location by bmesh frame by frame? I tried below way but failed. Is it possible to generate polygon movement animation effects like in Animation Nodes but by python?

```
bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_monkey_add(size=2, location = (0,0,0))
obj = bpy.context.object
obj.name='myobj'
me = obj.data

ico0 = np.array([v.co for v in me.vertices]) # get ico vertices

#find out Zvalue
zmin, zmax = ico0[:,2].min(), ico0[:,2].max()
zc = np.linspace(zmin, zmax, n_frames)
#print(zmin, zmax,zc)
#return
ico = np.zeros_like(ico0)
```

Comment: Look here https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/14055/how-to-use-bmesh-ops-transform

Comment: AFAICT your new question is this one dressed up a bit. Have marked this one a dupe of that rather than vice-versa.   Noticed your comment requesting help.  In a prior comment to you, I suggested  considering upvoting posts you find helpful, and accepting answers that answer your question.  The longer you do neither the less likely others will be to answer your questions.  Two of your 3 upvotes are from me to make you a _citizen_ of this site who can vote.

Comment: Alright!Just found that your posts are really helpful!!@batFINGER